# Particular Pesach Halochos historical trends

Tags: halacha-theory, passover

I'm looking for particular Pesach Halochos that were either permitted in the times of the Gemmorah or Rishonim and forbidden later by the Achronim or the contemporary Rabbis and the vice verse - that were forbidden and got permitted.

Comment: Kitniyot, gebrokts

Answer (score 2):

[Pesachim 114b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.114b.8?lang=bi) tells us that Rav Huna and Rava would have rice at the Seder.

[Rema Orach Chaim 453:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.453.1?lang=bi) writes that the custom is to forbid eating rice on Pesach.

Comment: Some Tannaim even avoided rice on Pesach

Comment: @DonielF Because they believed rice is בא לידי חימוץ